# How to add Rete.js visual programming editor in my React Component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to include the [Rete.js](https://github.com/retejs/rete) in react, I've tried what the documentation says, but getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
new EditorView
src/view/index.ts:25
  22 | this.container = container;
  23 | this.components = components;
  24 | 
> 25 | this.container.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

Here is my code snippet

```js
import React from 'react';

import Rete from "rete";
import ConnectionPlugin from 'rete-connection-plugin';
import ReactRenderPlugin from 'rete-react-render-plugin';


const numSocket = new Rete.Socket('Number value');

class NumComponent extends Rete.Component {
  constructor() {
    super('Number');
  }

  builder(node) {
    let out = new Rete.Output('num', 'Number', numSocket);

    node.addOutput(out);
  }

  worker(node, inputs, outputs) {
    outputs['num'] = node.data.num;
  }
}

const container = document.querySelector('#rete');
const editor = new Rete.NodeEditor('demo@0.1.0', container);

editor.use(ConnectionPlugin)
editor.use(ReactRenderPlugin)

const numComponent = new NumComponent();
editor.register(numComponent);

const engine = new Rete.Engine('demo@0.1.0');
engine.register(numComponent);

editor.on('process nodecreated noderemoved connectioncreated connectionremoved', async () => {
    await engine.abort();
    await engine.process(editor.toJSON());
});


const Dashboard = () => {

  return (
    
    <div id="rete"></div>

  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Please help me fix this, I've been trying to get this to work for quite sometime now without. Would be great if someone could help.

Comment: This was one of the possible solutions stated in the repository: https://github.com/retejs/rete/issues/433

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it to early, you haven't rendered the container yet. Put the construction into a useEffect / componentDidUpdate.